# What exactly are deep learning primitives?

Tags: deep-learning, architecture

I came across the concept of **"deep learning primitives"** from the Nvidia talk [Jetson AGX Xavier New Era Autonomous Machines](https://info.nvidia.com/rs/156-OFN-742/images/Jetson_AGX_Xavier_New_Era_Autonomous_Machines.pdf) (on slide 44).

There doesn't seem to be a lot of articles in the community on this concept. I was able to find one definition from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tensorflow-for-deep/9781491980446/ch01.html), where it defined deep learning primitives as the "fundamental building blocks of deep networks" like fully connected layers, convolutions layers, etc.

I was curious to find out if a **self-attention layer** is a primitive, I came across this [OpenDNN issue](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDNN/issues/533) and one person explained that self-attention layers can be built by other primitives like inner product, concat, etc.

So my question is what exactly are **primitives** in deep learning? What makes a convolution layer a primitive and a self-attention layer not a primitive?

Comment: Slide 44 only says "DEEP VISION PRIMITIVES" and then they provide examples of computer vision tasks, so I am not sure where, in that slide, you saw the term "deep learning primitives".

Comment: I thought the concept of primitives would generalise to beyond just vision tasks? The second link gives a definition of deep learning primitives: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tensorflow-for-deep/9781491980446/ch01.html